# Very slow hostname resolution in Windows XPe

Tags: tcpip, hostname, netbios, windows-xp-embedded

Hopefully a simple question to answer.

I've built an XP Embedded image, and it takes from between 17 and 25 seconds for me to resolve to an IP when I ping google.com.  Once it gets the IP address, the pings are just fine.

If I ping the IP directly it works just fine.  Finally, if I use nslookup, I get a response back instantly.

This machine has 2 NICs, and I've tried disabling that which wasn't used, and have also tried disabling IPv6.

Many thanks for any help in advance!

**Update:** When I type nslookup at the command prompt, I get the following welcome message:

```
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Can't find server name for address 192.168.1.254: Timed out
*** Default servers are not available
Default Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.254
```

Comment: See if using a different DNS works (Like the Public Google DNS server:  8.8.8.8)

Comment: I think you're onto something, as it fixes it.  I've updated my original post with a useful comment regarding a response I get from nslookup.  Many thanks.

Comment: Can you post the output of `ipconfig /all` on the prompt without the Google DNS set?

Comment: I've pulled the box off my desk and am onto another project, but I've answered my own question (with your help) below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On our local network the DNS server was not returning a reverse DNS entry for its own IP address.  This slowed the first hop of the tracert down (to a delay of around 17 to 25 seconds).

BloodPhilia suggested trying Google's DNS server, which did have a reverse DNS entry for their own IP.

The problem was solved by uninstalling the IPv6 adapter (it had previously only been disabled).

Comment: Glad I could point you in the right direction (: